# I cannot get Handlebars helpers to work with arguments in meteorjs

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

I'm trying to use a simple handlebars helper, with arguments, in MeteorJS.

Let me show you an example:

```
{{#myList data className="myClassName"}}
  {{name}}
{{/myList}}
```

The helper is declared this way:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('myList', function(context, options) {
  if (context && context.length){
    var className = options.hash.className || "", 
       ret = "<ul class='"+ className +"'>";

    for(var i=0, j=context.length; i<j; i++) {
      ret = ret + options.fn(context[i]);
    }

    return ret + "</ul>";
  }
});
```

But the property "hash" is ALWAYS an empty array.

If I test a version like this one:

```
{{#myList data "myClassName"}}
  {{name}}
{{/myList}}
```

The callback method never receive the second argument.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [meteor/handlebars](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Handlebars):

> In Meteor, block helpers do not take arbtirary positional and keyword
>   arguments like non-block helpers. Instead, the arguments are treated
>   together as a nested Handlebars helper invocation expression.

But you should be able to pass **only** keyword arguments:

> The exact rule is that a block helper is always invoked with either no
>   arguments; one positional argument (and no keyword arguments); or only
>   keyword arguments. The presence of any non-keyword argument, like foo
>   in the previous example, causes all following positional and keyword
>   arguments to be passed to foo (if it is a function, or else
>   swallowed). Otherwise, if there are only keyword arguments, they are
>   passed to the helper, so you can define a block helper that takes any
>   number of arguments by giving them names: {{#helper x=1 y=2
>   z=3}}...{{/helper}}.

This should work:

```
{{#myList myData=data className="myClassName"}}
  {{name}}
{{/myList}}
```

Comment: Not really ! Does it mean it is not possible this way, but that we can do it another way? How?

Comment: Tested and approved! Thanks!